# How are the two definitions of $\vec B \, $, as magnetic field and magnetic flux density, same?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

My question, is primarily, based on [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/413674/can-someone-please-explain-the-concept-b-regarding-magnetic-fields) question, in which the accepted answer asserts that $\vec B \, $ has two definitions,

1. As magnetic field$^*$, using Lorentz force $\vec F=q \vec v \times \vec B $
2. As magnetic flux density, from $\Phi=\int\vec B.d\vec S$

My question is how do these two definitions, result in the same vector field?

---

$*$  I'm not able to define $\vec B$ as I could define $\vec E$, as force per unit charge. Is there one such definition for $\vec B$, or was it introduced, so that we could formulate our observations easily with such a vector field?

In laws of induction, we use B as flux density and while finding the Lorentz force, we use it as a vector field whose magnitude is given by Biot-Savart law. How are these two equal?

Comment: I don't think the answer you refer to really does claim that these are both definitions. The relation involving $\Phi$ can't define $B$ unless you already have a definition of $\Phi$.

Comment: @BenCrowell Then I really don't understand that answer and my question is the same as that. In laws of induction, we use B as flux density and while finding the Lorentz force, we use it as a vector field whose magnitude is given by Biot-Savart law. How are these two equal?